# Establish socket io connection between 2 different apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I want to establish a socket.io connection between 2 different apps.
[image]

I want to implement chat system between users in APP1 and users in APP2 and to display notifications based on actions made on APP1 and APP2

I have found a lot of tutorials on socket io but each one of them was about implementing it on the same app.

I couldn't find a solution to connect 2 different apps.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Create a separate (third) server to which both of your apps will communicate/listen to.

Comment: `import { Server } from "socket.io";

const io = new Server(3000);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // send a message to the client
  socket.emit("hello from server", 1, "2", { 3: Buffer.from([4]) });

  // receive a message from the client
  socket.on("hello from client", (...args) => {
    // ...
  });
});`

how to make the socket io server listen to my 2 apps ? for example one on the port 3000 and the other on the port 3001

Comment: If you want to connect 2 clients behind a firewall directly together, you need a Server who routes them together by "udp punching hole" for example

Comment: Step 1: apps can't make sockets, only clients and servers can. Figure out where those arrows in the middle of your diagram actually go

Comment: this is my very first time with sockets, and I need to make a chat feature between app1 and app2. 2 different applications that share a chat system users from app1 can chat with users from app2. how to approach this ?

Comment: you said that already

Comment: Step 1: apps can't make sockets, only clients and servers can. Figure out where those arrows in the middle of your diagram actually go